# Значения аргументов функции по умолчанию ts

Tags: typescript

есть функция:

```
interface FindOptions {
    strict?: boolean;
    description?: string;
    type?: ProxyRequestBodyType;
    timeout?: number;
}

findRequest(
        foo,
        options: FindOptions,
    ) {
    // ...
}
```

если делать без интерфейса, то будет выглядеть так:

```
findRequest(
        foo,
        strict = true,  description = '', type = 'aa', timeout = 1000,
    ) {
    // ...
}
```

как-то можно задать значения в options по умолчанию?

Comment: ничто не мешает сделать то же самое с интерфейсом `{strict = true,  description = '', type = 'aa', timeout = 1000} : FindOptions`

Comment: Вопрос странен тем что у вас две разных функции. Первая принимает два аргумента, а вторая пять.

Comment: Вторая для примера, до того как я вынес это в опции @AlexeyTen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface FindOptions {
  strict?: boolean;
  description?: string;
  type?: ProxyRequestBodyType;
  timeout?: number;
}

function findRequest(
  foo,
  { strict = true, description = '', type = 'aa', timeout = 1000 }: FindOptions,
) {
  // ...
}
```